# How to install Ubuntu 11.04 after installing OpenSolaris.2009.06 without causing any problems?

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, opensolaris

I have installed `OpenSolaris.2009.06` on a server a few month ago, and have been working with it. Now I wanted to install Ubuntu 11.04. I have a large amount of sensitive data on OpenSolaris. Is there anyway to install `Ubuntu 11.04` without causing any problems to the existing data on the OpenSolaris. Like creating another partition etc. I have also tried googling, but almost all the sources are showing how to dual boot `Opensolaris` and `Ubuntu` from the `scratch`. Could someone help me in this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest path would be to simply install a second hard drive in the computer, for exclusive use by Ubuntu.

The problem is that OpenSolaris uses the ZFS filesystem by default, and as far as I know, there are no partition editing tools that know how to resize a ZFS partition on the fly. ZFS itself is a very dynamic filesystem, but it's geared more for splitting existing ZFS pools into multiple mount points, or taking over whole new disks/volumes by adding them to the pool. I don't believe ZFS knows how to give up part of a disk it is on.

If installing a second drive for Ubuntu is out of the question, your second best option is probably to back up your OpenSolaris installation and rebuild everything. You could look at it as an opportunity to try OpenIndiana or another of the post-OpenSolaris forks.

Comment: Thank you. I have developed some tools based on the libcpc and libpctx libraries of OpenSolaris.2009.06. Are there any major changes of these libraries in OpenIndiana? Please let me know.

Comment: I woudln't know. I can say that in my OI 148 installation, they both have `.so.1` endings to their file names. If yours are also `.1` versions, they should be completely compatible, even without relinking.

Comment: I just upgraded my OI VM to 151, and these libraries are still versioned `.1`.